# Folders' content doesn't refresh automatically

Tags: nautilus

I'm having the following issue on a fresh install of 12.10.
Basically if I create a file in a folder through a software (say, GIMP, or Libre), and I have Nautilus open as well, I don't see the file appearing in Nautilus. I have to close Nautilus, or switch to another folder and then switch back to the first folder... make sense?

I'm not sure where to look/what to do to fix.

Alex

Comment: You can refresh folder content by pressing F5.

Comment: Yes but shouldn't it be automatic?

Comment: From my experience it does refresh automatically but not all the time. Don't know why.

Comment: I also have this problem. It is specially bad when working with others in a shared folder

Comment: I have same problem with lubuntu, it even affected Sublime text editor where also folder content doesnt refresh. > python -mpyinotify /path/to/folder and > fs.inotify.max_user_watches did NOT helped here!!! Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if inotify subsystem ran out of the handles. Running `python -mpyinotify /path/to/folder` should display the requests to the filesystem that all applications can see. In case this does not work, neither will other applications.

The most likely case for running out of inotify handles is that some application (e.g. Dropbox or Ubuntu One) is tracking the changes in the directories.

In this case you will need to increase the value of `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` sysctl parameter.